# how to reduce size of the image in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, image

I want to reduce the size of image like this website
http://resizeimage.net
my image is 1080 x 360 size 120kb after I used the code below 
but when I use the website I get 58kb
or if there is a library or algorithm to compress JPEG file

```
func resizeImage(_ image: UIImage, newHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let scale = newHeight / image.size.height
    let newWidth = image.size.width * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage!, 0.5)! as Data
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return UIImage(data:imageData)!
}
```

Comment: Use a higher compression value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compression quality passed in to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` determines the image quality your JPEG image will be.  You have 0.5, try something lower like 0.1:

```
 let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage!, 0.1)! as Data
```

From Apple's Docs:

> `compressionQuality`: The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best quality).

Comment: but when I put  0.1 the image will look very bad

Comment: Yeah thats the tradeoff you get with image compression.  You could try different values anywhere between 0.1 and 0.5 to see if any of them give you good enough quality and the file size you're looking for.  Maybe 0.35 or 0.4 would be better.

Comment: Swift 5 - yourImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)